# How to set the Bit Length when generating SSL Certificate with Java keytool?

Tags: https, security-certificate, certificate-generation

I'm going to create a SSL Certificate so I can use https on my web site. I have to generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and I did generate such a file with the Java `keytool` following the guide [Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) on Tomcat](http://www.globalsign.com/support/csr/serversign_tomcat.php), but when I upload my CSR, I get a message from GlobalSign:

> We suggest that a Bit Length of 2048 bits is used when generating your CSR.
>   Please regenerate your CSR and select this Bit Length.

So how do I set the Bit Length to 2048 bits using the Java `keytool`?

I generated the CSR file with: `keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias your_alias_name -file certreq.csr -keystore your_keystore_filename`

And before that I created my certificate keystore and private key with: `keytool -genkey -alias your_alaias_name -keyalg RSA -keystore your_keystore_filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-keysize 2048`

Source: [CSR Generation: Java-based Webservers (using keytool)](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=244)